# UITableView selection state goes away in editing mode

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a UITableView where I select multiple rows.
I want to be able to swipe and delete few of them.

As soon as I swipe a cell, All my selected rows become unselected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can not be obtained by using default cell behaviour..

**Alternate way is**

Whenever you select any cell add that rownumber in an array. reselecting it must remove that index from the array. Soon after select change the background of the cell such that it looks as selected.

Comment: I was using a gray selection style. How do I get a background color that exactly matches it.

Comment: Background color is hard to get.. But you can always set an image ;)

Comment: If I scroll mt tableView, because of the reuse of the cells. a lot of my selected cells become unselected.

Comment: Change teh @"cellidentifier" to [nsstring stringwithFormat @"cellIdentifier%d%d",indexpath.section,indexpath.row];